# Send Image as data in Core Bluetooth

Tags: ios, image, core-bluetooth

I want to send an image from one device to another using core bluetooth framework. I am able to send string data. How to send an image between two devices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In exactly the same way that you send the string data. Get the image data with `UIImageJPEGRepresentation`.

If you need to limit so that you don't send too much at any one time, you can split the data into packets using `getBytes:range:` (or `subdataWithRange:`).

Comment: i tried using uiimagepngrepresentation(image) to send it but it was giving some exception NSInternalInconsistencyException.. is their any other way we can send image file.

Comment: Add the exception to your question, both message and stack trace. No, you need to send the image data.

Comment: Note that Core Bluetooth does not offer very high throughput, and may only be used for relatively small images.